# Laravel Catch Any Route with Prefix?

Tags: laravel

So currently in my Laravel app I've got the route;
`Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');`

And in this state, it works. However I want to add a prefix to it such as `/app/{any}` and for it to be inclusive of app as well. So `/app` would still go to `SinglePageController`.

I've tried doing something like that and it works for everything except the `/app` route itself.

Hopefully someone can provide some suggestions.

Comment: Did you tried to make `any` parameter optional? `{any?}`

Comment: Note that probably your route will match with `app/foo` but not with `app/foo/bar`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::group(["prefix" => "app"], function(){
    Route::get('/{any?}', 'SinglePageController@index');
}
```

I converted the `any` parameter to optional, so it can go to `SinglePageController@index` when it's not given too.

Also you may define the parameter of the index method as optional too. Like:

```
public function index($any = null){
```